# Vocês não gostam de um swing?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, perguntas-fechadas

Calma, o `swing` a qual me refiro é esse: [Java Swing](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29).

O que acontece é, [*essa pergunta*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59513/4808) foi fechada como fora de escopo. Óras, se a dúvida é sobre [*uma ferramenta comum entre programadores*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) isto não torna um pouco confuso para o AP entender qual foi o motivo dela ter sido suspensa?

Eu dei meu voto para fechar, mas por ela ser ampla. O Swing possui inúmeros recursos e enquanto a pergunta "é preciso instalar?" pode ser facilmente respondida, a segunda "como funciona?" daria para escrever um livro. E ainda assim, escrevendo o tal livro pode ser que não responda a dúvida do AP.

Eu comentei sobre o assunto no chat e recomendaram editar a pergunta. Mas aí que está, não tem o que editar, pode ser que uma edição torne a dúvida mais ampla ainda.

Eu acredito que essa pergunta pode agregar muito valor e trazer boas respostas, pois é um assunto muito procurado por boa parte dos iniciantes, eu mesmo lembro que já passei por isso, não aguentava mais escrever meus programas na faculdade rodando em console.

Interface gráfica é outro esquema, é o swing da coisa ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°).

Gostaria de indicá-la para reabertura, mas não na forma como está.
O que fazer nesse caso?

<sub><sub>Espero que ela não tenha sido suspensa por causa do meu comentário, dando a entender que era um assunto *off-topic*.</sub></sub>

Comment: Também concordo que, se for pra ficar fechada, o motivo correto seria "muito ampla". Mas não é costume reabrir uma pergunta só pra fechá-la de novo com o motivo "certo", se já está fechada deixa assim e pronto! De todo modo, não creio que essa pergunta seja "irrespondível" - não dá pra explicar com detalhes cada componentezinho do swing, é claro, mas dar uma visão geral, falar "assim se cria uma janela", "assim se põe componentes numa janela" e "assim se põe *listeners*, e cuidado que o código dos listeners roda fora do thread principal", mais uns links pra onde aprender mais, acho que rola.

Comment: Eu solicitei o fechamento assim, pois o autor não especificou um código, ele me parecia perguntar por algo como uma "aula", talvez eu tenha interpretado mal, mas foi assim que imaginei na hora. Mas realmente posso ter me precipitado.

Comment: De qualquer forma votei para reabrir.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não esquenta, abri esse debate justamente para resolver. #no #problem :)

Comment: Eu acho que o autor está mais preocupado em receber um pontapé inicial. Votei para reabrir. PS: fico imaginando em quantos milisegundos essa pergunta teria sido fechada e virado motivos de piada no SOEN.

Comment: PPS: não vejo a hora de recebermos o layout novo para eu não ter que ficar caçando links passando o mouse palavra por palavra na publicação inteira.

Comment: A pergunta foi reaberta, embora eu particularmente seja contra. Não quero entrar numa guerra de close-reopen, então o que podemos fazer para o autor da pergunta melhorar ela de forma que ela deixe de ser ampla e vaga demais?

Comment: Uma pergunta off: Vocês conseguem enxergar os links no META, eu só consigo ver os que não visitei, os que visitei parece que a cor se mistura com o texto. Nota: Eu acho que sou daltônico do verde-vermelho (enxergo sim essas cores, o que não enxergo são alguns tons especificos :p ). Eu vi alguém reclamando disto no meta.stackoverflow.com também.

Comment: Título ofensivo. Faz mais.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Desculpe ser chato, mas sou a favor de manter esta questão fechada.

Só para se ter uma ideia, tenho um livro inteiro sobre Swing que poderia ser a resposta para essa pergunta, e portanto ela é ampla demais.

Além disso, o autor da pergunta pede "como faço para usar Swing?", mas usar em qual sentido? Sem o autor dizer exatamente o que você quer dizer com isso, iria da cabeça de cada um que vier responder, e boa parte das respostas não seria o que ele queria dizer. Portanto esta pergunta é muito vaga.

Eu poderia responder ela como "para usar, basta você abrir o seu programa que roda em Swing e então manipulá-lo de acordo com as regras do programa usando o mouse e o teclado". Isso seria uma resposta válida, mas provavelmente não é o que ele quer.

Outra possível resposta seria "basta você importar as classes pertinentes do pacote `javax.swing` e usá-las", mas isso seria uma resposta realmente inútil, apesar de responder a pergunta.

Atualmente, há uma resposta mostrando um `JOptionPane`. Legal, mas...

- Para usar o swing é só fazer isso? [não]
- O que mais possso fazer com o swing? [um monte de coisas]
- É isso que o autor da pergunta queria fazer com o swing? [provavelmente não]

Ou então eu poderia responder assim:

> > Estou aprendendo Java Eclipse e gostaria de saber como faço para usar Swing.
>
> Legal
>
> > É preciso instalar?
>
> Não
>
> > Como funciona?
>
> Dentro da JVM há `handlers` para código-nativo que interagem com as APIs gráficas de cada sistema operacional. Além disso, para garantir a portabilidade, o desenho e o comportamento dos componentes é realizado e gerenciado inteiramente no lado do Java, bem como grande parte do gerenciamento de eventos, que roda por cima do AWT. O sistema operacional fica encarregado apenas do gerenciamento básico dos eventos, especialmente o que concerne ao teclado e ao mouse, e entrega ao Swing um conjunto de superfícies para ele realizar o desenho das janelas.

Talvez isso até seja uma resposta legal, mas... É isso que o autor da pergunta quer ou será que eu errei bem longe? Não dá para saber, pois **a pergunta é ampla e vaga demais!**

Além disso, imagine que eu fizesse essas perguntas:

> Estou aprendendo C++ Visual Studio e gostaria de saber como faço para usar C++.
>
> É preciso instalar? Como funciona?

> Estou aprendendo bancos de dados HeidiSQL e gostaria de saber como faço para usar SQL.
>
> É preciso instalar? Como funciona?

Essas perguntas são tão amplas e vagas quanto a outra, e exatamente por este motivo que ela deveria permanecer fechada. Além disso, o fato de o autor se referir como *Java Eclipse* mostra que ele nem sabe direito do que ele está falando.

Ok, e o que eu devo sugerir ao autor? Eu iria sugerir direções para um primeiro passo, algo como:

> Como desenvolver um Hello World em uma tela Swing?

E isso já seria algo bem mais respondível de forma objetiva, e daria um bom começo ao autor. Além disso, provavelmente isso não seria nenhuma das respostas da referida pergunta.

Comment: O que eu tinha entendido desde o princípio era "Como eu faço para usar o Swing". A resposta seria: baixe o Eclipse, baixe o plugin do WindowBuilder, crie uma classe através do botão tal (que já vem com o JFrame e a área de edição) e edite o código no lugar tal. Eu não entendi em momento algum que ele queria um tutorial de Swing, mas tenho que concordar que posso estar enganado e no meio de tantas dúvidas realmente é bem provável que cada um entenda de um jeito e cada um saia respondendo um monte de coisas diferentes. O melhor seria o AP dar o parecer e dizer o que ele realmente precisa. +1

Comment: Eu concordo que ela é ampla (muito) mas ela foi suspensa como *off-topic* e isso deixou tudo confuso - *recentemente também vi uma pergunta sobre Sublime Text ter o mesmo fim, enquanto há outras Notepad++ OK, não é confuso?! -* Na verdade eu esperava que o próprio AP editasse a pergunta sendo mais especifico antes de reabrir, o comentário do Math deixou claro que estávamos interessados na dúvida dele, mas que precisava ser um pouco mais especifico. Devemos esperar mais um pouco por uma edição feita pelo AP?

Comment: Concordo devia estar fechada

Comment: Discordo. Interpretei a pergunta da mesma maneira que o Math, entendendo que basta explicar os primeiros passos normais para se começar a usar o Swing. Os exemplos de resposta que você deu são tão propositadamente obtusos e vagos que é possível aplicá-los à quase todas as perguntas do site. Sob essa lógica [nossa 2a melhor pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2539/12) poderia ser respondida com "Talvez, depende". Além disso os exemplos de perguntas equivalentes são sobre 2 linguagens de programação e não sobre bibliotecas, e por isso com escopos bem distintos.

Answer (score -3):

Acredito que esta atitude de suspender a pergunta ao invés de editá-la pode resultar em duas coisas que, acredito, não queremos:

1. Afastar o usuário da comunidade;
2. Dificultar o aprendizado dele (o que, definitivamente, não é o intuito deste site).

Acho que, antes de mais nada, este tipo de pergunta pode ser perfeitamente editado para alguma coisa na seguinte linha: "Por onde começar? Qual é o melhor lugar para aprender?".

Depois disto, eu vejo dois caminhos possíveis:

1. Indicar tutoriais iniciais básicos e "oficiais" para o autor da pergunta (no caso do exemplo aqui em questão, [este link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html) é um caminho...);
2. Seguindo a linha de raciocínio do autor desta discussão aqui (Renan) durante uma produtiva conversa no nosso chat: ver um tutorial na Internet (que seja de fonte confiável, como o site da organização responsável pela dada tecnologia ou alguma aula disponível na página de alguma universidade confiável, etc.) e elaborar uma resposta mais técnica baseando-se nisto, incluindo links da documentação oficial, etc.

Alguns questionam a questão dos links de tutoriais em respostas alegando a questão da volatibilidade (os links podem mudar, etc.), mas é impossível lidar com programação e tecnologia sem levar em consideração que tudo que hoje é de um jeito pode ser bem diferente daqui a algum tempo; faz parte!

O importante é manter a comunidade constantemente atualizada, em movimento, atraindo novos membros e mostrando os caminhos certos para os novos usuários que chegam sem saber o que perguntar e como fazer isto.

Comment: As wikis de tags costumam ser um bom local para esse tipo de informação (tutoriais, etc). Atualmente, há muito pouco na tag [`swing`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info), mas outras contém mais recursos (ex.: [`java`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)). Acho que pouca gente se dá ao trabalho de editar essas wikis, primeiro porque não dá reputação (exceto os +2 por edição sugerida), segundo porque quase ninguém sabe que elas existem, então a pessoa tem trabalho pra editar e acaba não tendo nenhum impacto significativo...

Comment: O intuito de "suspender" soa mal a principio, mas não tem nada haver com **deletar** ou trancar **definitivamente**, o problema é que a palavra suspender não da a entender o sentido que é esperado. Agora cá entre nós, se o autor tem preguiça de ler a nota que vai abaixo da pergunta quando ela é suspensa não há muito o que fazer, veja minha opinião completa: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635

Comment: Sobre este teu comentário *"mostrando os caminhos certos para os novos usuários que chegam sem saber o que perguntar e como fazer isto"*, a primeira tela que aparece é o "Tour" quando a pessoa se loga a primeira vez (me corrija se eu estiver enganado) e muitas vezes ele vai no erro porque prefere ignorar a orientação. Sinceramente, eles pensam que isto é um fórum de suporte e uma simples visita no tour já ajudaria a evitar erros. Não me leve a mal por favor.

Comment: Já aconteceu várias vezes de editarem uma pergunta e mudar completamente o sentido dela, um sábio chinês me disse que as famosas "pergunta camaleão" nascem assim. Esse "edita aqui~edita lá" pode levar os demais usuários a se esforçarem criando respostas em vão. Eu penso que, perguntas onde não está claro qual é a dúvida, cabe somente ao AP editar. Se fosse um papel da comunidade adivinhar o que se passa, não teria um motivo "não é claro o que você está perguntando" na aba de suspensão. Quando há alguns erros, mas ainda assim é possível entender qual é o problema, podemos editar e melhorá-la.

Comment: "Por onde começar? Qual é o melhor lugar para aprender?", deve se tomar cuidado com esse tipo de pergunta, pode ser considerada "principalmente baseada em opiniões".

Comment: Me desculpe mas eu tive que negativar. Na minha opinião você sugeriu duas coisas que eu discordo: 1) Que suspender seja algo maléfico. Suspender faz parte do sistema, não podemos deixar de suspender as coisas se elas devem ser suspendidas. Suspensão não necessariamente afasta as pessoas ou dificulta o aprendizado, o que eu acredito que pode fazer isso é a falta de educação e respeito uns com os outros. (Não estou dizendo que isso ocorreu, é uma situação hipotética para atingir o resultado que você sugeriu)

Comment: 2) Editar a publicação ao ponto de alterar o sentido original dela. Pelo meu entendimento (posso estar errado), ele está mais preocupado em saber como começar a usar, isso envolveria basicamente instalar o WindowBuilder e explicar a estrutura da coisa. Não temos como garantir que eu esteja certo, nem que "Qual é o melhor lugar para aprender?" era a intenção do AP, portanto a edição a esse ponto estaria incorreta. PS: não estou te recriminando, esse é meu ponto de vista. Sinta-se a vontade para discordar.

Comment: Mais uma que eu não tinha percebido: "Indicar tutoriais iniciais básicos e "oficiais" para o autor da pergunta". S´´ se for nos comentários, por favor não faça isso no campo da resposta. E já que é para comentar então não é necessário reabrí-la :)