# Campanha: Fechamento justo e explicado. Reabertura justa e explicada

Tags: debate, fechamento, razões-fechamento, perguntas-fechadas

## Nosso problema

Na minha opinião, estamos com um problema sério no nosso Stack Overflow em português referente ao fechamento de questões. Aliás, um não, vários:

- O fechamento de perguntas sem maiores explicações.
- O fechamento de perguntas pelos motivos errados.
- Pessoas votando para fechar perguntas sem avaliar criticamente o fechamento.
- Pessoas votando para reabrir perguntas sem avaliar criticamente o fechamento e a reabertura.

Em especial, cito [este incidente recente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2686/132) e [este outro incidente recente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2692/132). Mas esses não são casos isolados, já vi coisas parecidas acontecerem por aqui várias vezes mesmo sem ir ao meta.

Outro exemplo, [é esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59379/132), o autor concordou que se tratava de duplicata, mesmo assim temos 4 votos para reabrir.

Outro dia, teve uma pergunta fechada muito mal-feita, em que editei o conteúdo para arrumar os erros de português. Isso imediatamente a fez entrar na fila de análise para reabertura e recebeu pelo menos um voto de reabertura.

Também já vi coisas assim acontecendo várias outras vezes.

Note que não estou questionando a validade de se fechar e nem de se reabrir perguntas, estou questionando se isto está sendo feito de forma responsável.

Então, a minha hipótese é que está ocorrendo mais ou menos o seguinte:

1. Alguém posta uma pergunta muito ruim, mas sobre um tema legal.
2. Uma outra pessoa vota para fechar, afinal a pergunta é muito ruim e tem sérios problemas. Mas escolhe o motivo de fechamento errado. O motivo de escolher o motivo errado pode ser por inexperiência ou falta de habilidade em usar o site, ou pode ser por preguiça de pensar e desleixo mesmo.
3. Outras pessoas veem a pergunta na fila de análise e fazem uma "avaliação crítica" de uns 5 segundos, concordando com o fechamento e com o motivo como se fossem zumbis.
4. A pergunta acaba sendo fechada sem nenhum comentário acerca disso pelo motivo errado.
5. O autor da pergunta não entende o que está acontecendo e é pego de surpresa, pois usuários com baixa reputação não podem ver votos de fechamento.
6. O autor da pergunta começa a reclamar nos comentários ou então abandona o site.
7. As pessoas que fecharam a pergunta não veem e desconhecem os comentários que o autor postou reclamando.
8. Alguém edita a pergunta para corrigir erros de português ou alguma coisa do tipo.
9. A pergunta vai para a fila de análise de reabertura, aonde as pessoas novamente fazem uma "avaliação crítica" de uns 5 segundos e reabrem a pergunta como se fossem zumbis.
10. A pergunta acaba sendo reaberta de forma tão misteriosa e inexplicável quanto foi fechada.
11. O SOpt começa a ficar uma bagunça, bons novos usuários se afastam, maus novos usuários ficam e a qualidade das perguntas vai caindo!

## Minha sugestão

Então a minha sugestão é fazermos uma campanha de conscientização:

1. Se você vai votar para fechar uma pergunta, coloque algum comentário explicando detalhadamente a razão para o fechamento, tanto para o autor da pergunta quanto para os demais colegas, mesmo que o motivo seja muito óbvio. A menos, é claro, que alguma outra pessoa já tenha feito tal comentário e você nada tenha a adicionar.
2. Se você vai votar para reabrir uma pergunta, coloque algum comentário explicando detalhadamente a razão para a reabertura, tanto para o autor da pergunta quanto para os demais colegas, mesmo que o motivo seja muito óbvio. A menos, é claro, que alguma outra pessoa já tenha feito tal comentário e você nada tenha a adicionar.
3. Se você está vendo uma pergunta na fila de análise de fechamento, leia a pergunta com calma e com atenção, prestando atenção nos detalhes e leia todos os comentários, em especial, procurando quais são as razões para o fechamento. Se houverem respostas, leia-as também. Só depois de fazer isso, decida se concorda ou não com o fechamento, mas faça um julgamento crítico pensando por ambos os lados, e não apenas uma aceitação automática e passiva para o fechamento como se fosse um zumbi. Se estiver em dúvida, clique no botão "Pular" ou poste algum comentário pedindo maiores esclarecimentos.
4. Se você está vendo uma pergunta na fila de análise de reabertura, leia a pergunta com calma e com atenção, prestando atenção nos detalhes e leia todos os comentários, em especial, procurando quais foram as razões para o fechamento e quais são as razões para a reabertura. Se houverem respostas, leia-as também. Só depois de fazer isso, decida se concorda ou não com a reabertura, mas faça um julgamento crítico pensando por ambos os lados, e não apenas uma aceitação automática e passiva para a reabertura como se fosse um zumbi. Se estiver em dúvida, clique no botão "Pular" ou poste algum comentário pedindo maiores esclarecimentos.
5. Se você concordou com o fechamento, escolha o motivo que você usaria para fechar a questão, e não apenas o motivo que os outros escolheram. Se as pessoas que escolheram fechar anteriormente deram um motivo diferente do seu, poste um comentário explicando o seu motivo de fechamento.
6. Se você ver alguém votando para fechar ou para reabrir aparentemente sem seguir as diretrizes acima, poste um comentário na questão convidando-o, de forma educada, gentil e cordial, a prestar maiores esclarecimentos. Se julgar pertinente, traga a questão para o meta.
7. Lembre-se de comentar e/ou editar a pergunta (se necessário) ANTES de votar pelo fechamento ou reabertura, e não depois. Isso reduz a possibilidade de outros usuários votarem como zumbis ou não entenderem o seu motivo de fechamento ou reabertura.

Enfim, a campanha se resume a:

- Estimular nossos usuários a pensar criticamente os votos de fechamento e reabertura;
- Postar comentários explicando e debatendo o fechamento e a reabertura e;
- Convidar os demais usuários a fazer o mesmo.

E sempre lembre-se:

- Use o seu cérebro para votar, não vote como um zumbi.
- Votar para fechar ou para reabrir é uma grande responsabilidade. Não seja irresponsável com isso.

Ah, e antes que alguém venha me atacar, não estou querendo apontar o dedo para ninguém (pelo menos não aqui) para acusar a pessoa A ou a pessoa B de ter votado de forma irresponsável/automática/zumbi pelo fechamento ou reabertura da questão X ou Y. O objetivo aqui é principalmente estimular o debate e a explicação para as razões do fechamento e reabertura em todas as questões aonde isso acontecer daqui para frente.

Comment: Acho que falta um tópico importantíssimo. Cuidado com as edições a perguntas fechadas. Se está fechada com pedidos de esclarecimento ao AP para que editar? E quando estiver na fila de analise como duplicata ter o cuidado de editar antes de votar para fechar, para que não volte logo de seguida para reabertura.

Comment: @JorgeB. Há vários motivos para se editar uma pergunta fechada ou que vai ser fechada. Um deles é deixá-la mais clara até para que os demais usuários entendam a pergunta e possam melhor orientar o AP. Outro motivo é para evitar downvotes não merecidos. Um terceiro motivo é para dar o exemplo e estimular o autor da pergunta e os demais usuários a editar. O fechamento da questão não deveria ser obstáculo para a edição, e o fato de estar sendo ou de poder ser é algo muito errado que precisa ser corrigido.

Comment: Tu não percebeste a ideia. Pode-se editar a pergunta e arranja-la antes dela ser fechada, evitando assim uma ida para a fila de reabertura. Tenho visto muitas perguntas na fila de reabertura só com algumas correções de texto e aspeto da pergunta.

Comment: @JorgeB. Ah sim. O problema é quando se edita a pergunta depois que outras pessoas a fecharam. Se for eu a votar pelo fechamento ou de fato querer a reabertura, então é fácil, mas normalmente não é o caso.

Comment: Mas não é essa a ideia da campanha? Que quem fecha a pergunta deixe comentário e edite a pergunta se for o caso?

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim. O problema são as pessoas que não leem os comentários. :)

Comment: Sim mas acho que era um tópico a colocar ali. Editar a pergunta, se for o caso, antes de fechar.

Comment: @JorgeB. Adicionei um item. Está legal?

Comment: @Earendul acho que a ideia do Victor é de colocar comentários construtivos para a pergunta, do género "o que você tentou fazer, mostre o código que tem"

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu punha "Lembre-se de comentar (e/ou editar se necessário) ANTES..."

Comment: @JorgeB. Feito. :) Muito obrigado. :)

Comment: @JorgeB. Verdade. Neste caso desconsidere o meu comentário. Estou meio lento hoje para interpretar certas coisas, :~

Comment: @VictorStafusa foi exatamente isso que você expôs que eu também fiz um debate. Acho muito desnecessário a pessoa votar para fechar sem ao menos explicar o porque.. Usuários novos se afastam por ficarem assustados...

Comment: Coloquei o debate em destaque no boletim da comunidade. Tenho visto seus comentários em várias perguntas, e estão excelentes. Espero que mais gente siga o exemplo.

Comment: Concordo com o @bfavaretto. Vamos lá comentar (sem exageros).

Comment: Coincidência ou não tenho visto menos perguntas na fila para fechar.

Comment: Julgo que um dos problemas é o baixo valor de reputação necessário para se obter o privilégio ***atribuir votos encerrados e reabertos***

Comment: Uma forma de incentivar os comentários úteis é votar neles, ;). Acho que tem uma medalha pra tantos votos em um comentário.

Comment: Vim aqui só dar os parabéns pela iniciativa.

Comment: Você deve ter percebido que eu tirei o destaque (tinha coisa demais no boletim já). Passado mais de um mês da sua postagem, você acha que o pessoal ficou mais consciente? Passou a fechar e reabrir melhor?

Comment: @bfavaretto Na minha visão, a situação deu uma melhorada significativa, mas ainda está abaixo do que deveria ser.

Comment: Pra mim não ficou tão claro se melhorou, mas andei menos presente no site nas últimas semanas. De qualquer maneira, antes um pássaro na mão do que dois voando, né?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Concordo com a maior parte da campanha (ter mais atenção antes de abrir ou fechar), eu mesmo a dois dias fechei uma por engano, mas não foi por falta de atenção e sim dificuldade de entendimento.

### O que eu discordo

É ter que justificar cada atitude sua, sendo que a ideia de um sistema automatizado (que é o StackExchange) é não precisar fazer isto. Se tem a mensagem no rodapé da pergunta quando suspensa para isto, com detalhes, então que o autor leia tal mensagem, se não ela seria desnecessária.

### O problema

Vai uma série de motivos do porque eu acho que a mensagem do **rodapé**  da pergunta não é tão intuitiva (quando ocorre o fechamento ou suspensão).

1. A palavra *[Suspensa]* adicionada ao título entoa quase como um *crime*

   Eu mesmo já sugeri trocar a palavra por *[Com pendencias]*, pois do meu ponto de vista o autor iria se interessar em saber que pendencias são essas.

   > Minha sugestão: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2374/3635
2. O texto do rodapé nem sempre é descritivo:

   Tá eu sei que isto soa estranho, ele é descritivo sim, o problema é que não fornece dicas muito claras para os novatos e todos tipos de fechamento.
3. Tradução da "ferramenta" (StackOverflow):

   Muitas coisas são traduzidas e o sentido é o mesmo, porém a cultura nossa Portugal, Brasil e Norte Americana, são culturas diferentes, por exemplo se eu chegar e pedir na barraca de cachorro quente `I want a hot dog` nos EUA, isto vai soar como uma ordem (vai soar mal), no Brasil se você disse `Eu quero um cachorro quente` não vai soar mal.

   Portanto as pessoas podem levar a mal só pelo simples fato de como uma frase pode parecer ríspida em uma cultura diferente.
4. Fóruns de ajuda e suporte para problemas específicos:

   Não, não somos tal tipo de fórum, nem somos fórum, somos aqui uma comunidade de "pergunta e respostas", debates devem ser evitados (claro que eu sei que a maioria sabe disto).

   O problema é que durante um bom tempo os fóruns foram muito populares na vida de muitos, com diversos temas, principalmente ligado a informática, então o usuário novo vem aqui sem saber o que são as ferramentas StackExchange, achando que aqui devemos simplesmente ajuda-los e não agregar nada a comunidade, pois isto não é importante e este fato simplesmente ocorre, porque as pessoas ignoram o **TOUR**, mesmo sendo a primeira tela que aparece quando você se cadastra (eu acho, faz algum tempo que me cadastrei, nem lembro mais se tal tela ainda aparece).

### Resumindo

A ferramenta é automatizada, deve ter os seus textos aprimorados e o recém chegado deve fazer no minimo o **TOUR**, o título *suspenso* deve ser trocado (não precisa ser a minha sugestão) e cada rodapé com detalhes do fechamento deve ter uma mensagem explicando que  "suspensão" e "fechamento" podem ser revertidos, mas que ele tem que ver os links **Tour** e **Help** para saber como fazer isto. Portanto eu acredito que deveria ser *automatizado*.

> **Só um comentário:**
>   Eu acho que assim como os novatos podem errar ao criar uma pergunta, os veteranos também podem errar e fechar por engano.

Comment: [15k+ usuários](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese), [1.8k que fizeram o tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). É...

Comment: [Com pendências] +1! Suspensa ou fechada é assustador mesmo! Até ver que alguém editou sua pergunta/resposta, pra quem não sabe como o sistema funciona, vai parecer meio (ou muito) invasivo dependendo da pessoa, mas que faz todo sentido quando se entende o que é um Q&A. Acontece que quando a pessoa chega aqui ela não tem ideia do que é um Q&A. E começar tendo a pergunta editada/suspensa/negativada não ajuda muito. :) Muito boa a ideia do [com pendências] imho.

Comment: @bfavaretto não seria o caso de obrigar a fazer o tour antes de deixar o sujeito postar?

Comment: @CarlosCinelli isto seria uma sugestão para o stackexchange, os moderadores não tem tal poder infelizmente

Comment: @bfavaretto [Nós somos o 5o site que mais lê o tour](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XvoED.png), e somos muito maiores que os outros à nossa frente.

Comment: Sim @Gabe mas acredito que isto devido ao forte incentivo pelos usuários mais antigos da casa, o que não é tão comum nas outras comunidades e com o perdão da palavra, mas fazer o tour não garante muito.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu não faço ideia de porque somos um dos sites que mais lê o tour, e também sei que ler o tour não significa muita coisa (assim como não ter lido o tour não significa muita coisa), também sei que ter a medalha sequer significa que a pessoa realmente *leu* o tour. Só estava colocando o fato apontado pelo bfavaretto em termos relativos. Na verdade nós lemos muito o tour, independente do número baixo absoluto.

Comment: @Gabe Entendi, realmente você tem razão

Comment: Discordo completamente com a troca da palavra "suspensa" por "com pendencias". Isso faz parecer que, para o sistema, uma pergunta é um conjunto de tarefas e que uma ou mais dessas tarefas ficou pendente no sistema, o que não tem lógica nem sentido.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel é a sua opinião, nem todos concordam comigo e nem todos discordam, apenas opinião. Você pode ir no link que forneci da outra pergunta e dar a sua sugestão com uma resposta. Eu pessoalmente acho que um sistema é um "conjunto de tarefas" que deve ser seguido pelo usuário.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Mas dizer que uma pergunta tem pendências é uma má ideia. Uma pergunta é um todo, e não uns quantos blocos de dados que são processados em separado. A minha sugestão é manter como está.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel está é sua opinião, você e outros usuários vêem como má ideia, outros usuários e eu veem como boa ideia, é apenas uma questão de OPINIÃO. Como eu disse tem várias opiniões no link da outra pergunta, poste a sua lá resposta como você disse no comentário "sugiro manter". Mas note que muitos usuários rejeitam o termo atual "suspensa" e isto tem causado algumas confusões, TALVEZ a minha sugestão não seja tão boa, mas está claro que "suspensa" também não está ajudando...

Comment: ...Como eu já disse, talvez a discordância quanto ao termo seja algo cultural, ao que notei você talvez você seja nascido em Portugal, note que nasci no Brasil e a sua discordância quanto a minha sugestão seja devido a fatores culturais, se for isto então sugiro não usar nem "suspensa" e nem "com pendências" e sim procurar um termo aceitável as duas culturas, claro que não tenho certeza deste ser o problema @IsmaelMiguel

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não é por causa da cultura. O que é uma coisa pendente? É algo que está encalhado. A pergunta não está encalhada. Apenas não está a 100%.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel independente do motivo e da sua opinião, "suspensa" também não está dando certo, se não houvesse problemas com "suspensa", não haveria tantas reclamações. Não precisa concordar com a minha sugestão, só tenha em mente que talvez seja necessário uma alternativa (não precisa ser a minha sugestão).

Comment: Só te dar uma opinião, como disse você não precisa concordar, mas para mim e alguns outros usuários quando a pergunta está suspensa ela está encalhada, pois não tem como respondê-la, já que as respostas estão bloqueadas e até que alguém edite e algum moderador ou outros usuário com privilégio tirem a suspensão ou fechem a pergunta para mim e alguns outros poucos usuários ela isto é sim encalhada, ou seja alguém tem que desencalhar ela. Isto é apenas uma opinião, como disse **nao precisa concordar** @IsmaelMiguel. De qualquer forma obrigado pela conversa, até mais.

Comment: Eu fui ver o tour semana passada, mas ingressei a mais de mês. Isso porquê para mim foi muito intuitivo, e cada falha que cometi(como titulo mal escrito, palavra chave) ficou claro(moderação sempre em cima, rsrs..) conforme fui usando essa ferramenta e acho que funciona assim com todos.. enquanto o fórum contar com pessoas como estas(que reportam por exemplo) o tour passa a não ser necessário e torna-se opção(minha opinião).

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus O tour é apenas uma sugestão, na verdade o melhor a indicar para usuário novos seria o Help. Sobre o ponto que você colocou "é muito intuitivo", eu concordo contigo e por isto formulei esta resposta, pois ao meu ver a ferramenta tem que prover a explicação, nós sermos obrigados a ficar dando satisfação é algo burocrático e cansativo. :) Obrigado por comentar. +1

Answer (score 6):

Concordo com todos os problemas citados,e é realmente necessário procurarmos uma solução, muito das soluções citadas nada mais é do que o "**bom senso**", acredito que não seja uma obrigatoriedade colocar um comentário ao votar, pela questão da praticidade citada também pelo @GuilhermeNascimento, muito da bagunça aqui vem da própria cultura brasileira ( me incluindo ) que é uma diversidade muito grande, tão visível não só na forma de escrever o texto mas também na forma de se expressar com gírias e máximas, eu já recebi uma resposta que me foi muito útil de um Sr. mas que da forma que foi escrita ficou muito ofensiva, então vejo que esse tipo coisa (intolerância) às vezes acaba sendo "expressada" em forma de votação seja suspender, fechar etc.

**SUGESTÃO**

Ser cordial o tempo todo, como disse às vezes você se depara com uma pergunta que o título não diz nada e a descrição menos ainda e da vontade de...**fechar** a pergunta na cara desse usuário que não sabe se é dia ou se é noite, mas, ao sentir essa vontade, você detentor de grande experiência seja no site, programação ou outros, peça no comentário para ele detalhar melhor o problema, se ele teve o trabalho de escrever, é porque ele tem sim um problema, lembre-se que você nasceu sem saber nada, você já esteve na situação de aprendiz, então trate a pessoa que tem dificuldade até em escrever o problema não do mesmo jeito que você gostaria de ser tratado, trate-o melhor ainda, é assim fazendo a pessoa se sentir muito bem vinda, que ela vai pegar gosto, vai sentir vontade de ajudar o próximo assim como ele foi ajudado, vai querer aprender a usar o SO e vai permanecer aqui.

Comment: Não ficou faltando alguma coisa para completar essa frase não? "mas, ao sentir essa vontade, você detentor de grande experiência seja no site, programação etc" ...

Comment: @Math editei a resposta, tava estranho mesmo

Comment: Eu mesmo as vezes tenho dificuldade em perceber perguntas por causa da gíria que vocês usam que eu não conheço.

Comment: Já agora fica uma sugestão. Separar o texto por assuntos é boa onda. Senão uma pessoa perde-se no meio de tanta virgula. Eu ia editar a sua pergunta mas achei melhor deixar como está e alertar.

Answer (score -2):

Recentemente tive [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217565/api-gratuita-para-hist%C3%B3rico-climatol%C3%B3gico) fechada por duplicata.

Antes dela ser fechada (quando tinha apenas 2 votos para fechá-la) fiz uma edição na pergunta explicando o porque dela não ter sido respondida na pergunta apontada como possível duplicata (Edição essa desnecessária, pois a pergunta original já era clara o suficiente, mas mesmo assim a fiz).

Mesmo assim, mais 3 pessoas votaram para minha pergunta ser fechada dizendo que ela era uma duplicata.

Essas atitudes já são/foram amplamente discutidas aqui no Stack Meta mas parece que continuam a acontecer, eu sou uma pessoa que começou a participar ativamente do stack há pouquíssimo tempo mas já me desanimei muito devido a essas atitudes.

Este [tópico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2693/campanha-fechamento-justo-e-explicado-reabertura-justa-e-explicada) disserta um pouco sobre o meu problema (que sei que acontece com muitos outros) e em uma das respostas um usuário até diz que *"Eu acho que assim como os novatos podem errar ao criar uma pergunta, os veteranos também podem errar e fechar por engano."* e eu concordo PLENAMENTE com isso, porém no caso de fechar uma pergunta é necessário 5 pessoas para fechá-la, será que 5 veteranos erraram ou desses 5 1 ou 2 erraram e os outros 3 apenas clicaram pra fechar sem ao menos ler a pergunta? Além disso, dos 5 que votaram apenas um deles tentou explicar/me ensinar o porque do fechamento.

Minha sugestão:

- Ao receber 5 votos para fechar a pergunta, a mesma deve ser analisada por uma sexta pessoa que então, explica para o autor pontualmente o porque da pergunta estar sendo fechada caso concorde com os outros 5;

Sei que isso gera um trabalho maior aos moderadores e que pode parecer desnecessário, porém enquanto tivermos pessoas dando downvote/sinalizações sem serem criteriosos acredito que minha sugestão seja válida.

Comment: Detalhe, se você ver a [revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/217565/revisions) da sua pergunta, vera que ela foi se alterando com o tempo.... e a pergunta só deslanchou mesmo nos comentários, você passou do [aonde acho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/217565/1) pro [como utilizo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217565/api-gratuita-para-hist%C3%B3rico-climatol%C3%B3gico#comment445562_217565)

Comment: Enfim, se a primeira pergunta poderia ser fechada como duplicada ou como não clara, a pergunta nos comentários poderia ser fechada como muito ampla (na minha opinião)

Comment: @MarceloBoni não entendi direito como mudei de aonde acho pra como utilizo na pergunta, as únicas edições que eu fiz foram pra deixar a pergunta mais clara e em nenhum momento perguntei como utilizar a API.  Com relação a fechar por muito ampla eu discordo pois, ela é no máximo muito específica (concordo que eu exagerei um pouco quando pedi uma API GRATUITA), é bem restrito isso e pode não ser tão util pra comunidade quanto seria uma indicação de uma API pra histórico climatologico paga, que alias, se fosse essa a pergunta estaria respondida pelo usuário Sidon.