# Você é mesmo objetivo? Ou só tem boa intenção? Que sugestões podem melhorar a plataforma?

Tags: suporte

Esse tópico cita três problemas de avaliação do StackOverflow, e pergunta sobre possíveis soluções e melhorias da plataforma.

O StackOveflow é um site de perguntas e respostas objetivas sobre programação[1]. O objetivo é a resposta a perguntas de problemas, sem a carga de discussão que tem nos tradicionais fóruns de discussão. Com isso, temos um formato para fazer perguntas. Uma outra característica da plataforma, é que ela em partes, é administrada pelos seus próprios membros, que supostamente avaliam essa subjetividade. E esse é um dos assuntos que trataremos a seguir.

Usando como exemplo, uma das atividades humanas que mais exigem objetividade, as ciências naturais, mesmo um dos principais filósofos, não acha que existe uma observação pura da realidade, que sempre tem alguma subjetividade em algum nível [2]. Se mesmo a nossa querida "ciência" há ruído até que uma ideia seja revisada e finalmente publicada, o que acontece se um grupo de entusiastas metódicos, e grande parte deles, antissociais (sem falácia da exceção por favor), que dominam apenas a tecnologia de seu próprio mercado, resolvem avaliar objetividade de novos usuários do StackOverflow? Para conseguir ilustrar, vamos citar alguns casos clássicos que vocês já viram por arqui (nem adianta negar).

**1.  Você não foi claro o suficiente. Essa questão é muito ampla.**

Acho que com certo número de pontos de reputação, deve habilitar um botão que faz esse post automático, não é possível minha gente! O mais curioso dessa questão, é que vemos acusações frequentes em tópicos, mas a questão é completamente clara para você que domina a tecnologia da tag inserida. E não existe nada de amplo ali! Daí temos os DownVoters**, fechamento de uma questão que poderia ajudar futuros usuários, e o pior: uma discussão sobre o formato da pergunta, sem que o o foco seja o problema. **Tirando todo o sentido da existência do StackOVerflow**. Casos em que a pergunta não é de verdade objetiva o suficiente existem (como eu mesmo já fiz recentemente), e não é assunto desse tópico.

Sugestão:

1. Evite dar avaliações de linguagens que você não domina por
   **COMPLETO!**. Uma questão que parece bem "ampla"para você, pode não ser para quem domina determina linguagem.
2. Dê pelo menos duas soluções ou cite dois assuntos do suposto tema
   "amplo". Sim! Por definição, se o assunto é amplo de verdade,
   **existem no mínimo**, duas abordagens ou duas soluções possíveis.
3. Terceira sugestão: **NÃO INTERESSA!** Sim, exatamente isso! Uma
   pergunta feita no Stack não passa a deixar de ser clara, pelo motivo
   de você não saber para que o usuário quer solucionar determinada
   dúvida. Se ele quiser discutir filosoficamente os motivos de fazer
   "X", ele iria num fórum ou no nosso chat. Então antes de negativar
   uma pergunta, fazer perguntas não construtivas do tipo "você não foi
   claro. Para quer fazer X coisa?", ou mesmo sugerir edição, apenas
   pare! Pergunte a si mesmo: Eu entendi a parte técnica da pergunta? Eu
   perguntei a ele na área de comentário para confirmar se eu entendi
   mal, ou ele que não foi objetivo? Uma pessoa arrogante não vai fazer nada disso. Mas você membro bem intencionado irá fazer essas perguntas.

--

**2. Ah, mas tem muito usuário que...** Por favor pare com isso! Todos nós em algum nível somos moderadores. Então quando criticamos construtivamente tanto a plataforma, quanto nosso comportamento, acredito que estamos melhorando a comunidade. Então se toda vez que formos fazer uma autocrítica, desviar o assunto para os defeitos do vizinho, não vamos amadurecer em nada. Mesmo na vida offline.

**3. Esse tema não faz parte do escopo do site**

Finalmente, só chegue a essa conclusão, se realmente o assunto não tiver haver com programação **por completo**. Evite taxar o assunto desse jeito, só porque ele está correlacionado com outro assunto. Certa vez um tópico foi fechado porque havia o assunto segurança no tópico. A dúvida era que padrões de código buscava no PHP para maior segurança. O tópico foi fechado porque existe um Stack Echange **em inglês** sobre segurança. Evite votar em fechamento de perguntas por essa bizarrice de motivos.

Eu não poderia terminar esse tópico sem repetir a pergunta principal dele: Quais sugestões poderiam solucionar esses tipos de problema?

**4.** **Essa pergunta foi marcada como duplicada** -> Não é tão incomum quanto deveria uma pergunta ser marcada como duplicada, quando lemos uma questão tratam de assuntos diferentes, e ainda são **abordadas** de formas diferente. Se desconfia que uma pergunta é duplicada, antes de marcar como duplicada, favor pelo menos ler os dois tópicos.

> ** Indivíduo que vota negativamente em post de forma desenfreada, normalmente sem comentar o motivo. Os motivos podem variar, desde
>   "upar" sua própria resposta, ou até pura trollagem mesmo. Ainda não é
>   o tópico para discutir sobre DownVoters. Se achar necessário, abra um
>   tópico sobre o assunto.
>
> [1] https://stackoverflow.com/company/about
>
> [2] http://www.publicadireito.com.br/artigos/?cod=fe131d7f5a6b38b2 ->
>   Página 7

Answer (score 8):

Na maioria das vezes que dou um voto de fechamento em alguma coisa por considerá-la não clara ou ampla demais, eu deixo ao menos um comentário explicando o que penso. Perguntas que abordam temas dos quais não entendo ou entendo muito pouco, eu tendo a pular no processo de revisão.

Entretanto, há várias pessoas por aqui que não tem lá muita paciência para isso. Se ao ler a pergunta, o texto pareceu ser confuso demais, já manda fechar. E muitas vezes essas pessoas nem comentam porque comentar dá trabalho e por vezes leva a longas conversas para esclarecer a pergunta, e nem todos tem disposição suficiente para isso.

Inclusive, vou dar como exemplo [essa pergunta sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176122/132). No começo, ela estava confusa e eu e o Luiz Vieira tivemos uma boa dificuldade para entender o que você queria. Parte disso é que você partiu de um pressuposto que não era verdadeiro (sobre o assembly). Depois de muita conversa entre todos nós, finalmente conseguimos elucidar tudo. Entretanto, esse foi um processo um tanto difícil tanto para você que perguntou quanto para quem estava disposto a responder. Nem todos têm paciência para levar esse processo a cabo. Além disso, você tomou votos negativos e votos de fechamento. Confesso que no começo eu dei voto negativo e voto de fechamento, mas a medida que a conversa foi se desenrolando e a questão foi sendo esclarecida, removi o meu voto de fechamento, removi o voto negativo e dei meu voto positivo. Vi agora que a pergunta acabou sendo fechada assim mesmo, por isso dei o meu voto de reabertura.

Entretanto, esse caso aí que citei é só um exemplo, existe milhares de outros no site. Os problemas em geral que levam muitas perguntas que poderiam ser boas acabarem indo para o lixo são ao meu ver os seguintes:

- Qualquer coisa que caia em algo [que está aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/132). Não foi a toa que criei esse tópico, pois a ideia não é só barrar perguntas ruins, mas também orientar as pessoas a não fazer perguntas ruins e se esforçarem em melhorar as suas perguntas.
- O autor da pergunta partir de pressupostos falsos e acabar por pedir uma coisa que não tenha lá muito sentido.
- O autor da pergunta pedir algo genérico usando termos vagos. Por exemplo: "*Ei, pessoal, alguém aí pode me explicar um pouco de PHP? Meu programa está com erro! Obrigado!*"
- Pedir links de sites, apostilas, fóruns ou tutoriais na pergunta. Isso daqui tende a ser fatal e irrita muitos usuários do site. Já vi vários casos de perguntas que seriam muito boas, mas acabam indo pro vinagre porque no final, o autor posta um "*e aí, alguém teria o link de um site para me indicar?*"
- [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132).
- [Gorila vs tubarão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/132).
- Não entender o que significa mínimo completo e verificável. Já vi inclusive gente falando de exemplo mínimo completo e verificável (MCVE) e o autor da pergunta confundir o MCVE com o padrão de projeto MVC, então bagunçar ainda mais com a pergunta e com os comentários.
- Perguntas incompletas. Inclusive perguntas com código incompleto.
- Revisores que não entendem do assunto, mas que mesmo assim tentam julgar uma questão complicada e cheia de nuances específicas.
- Gente que vota, não comenta nada e vai embora. Isso é extremamente comum por aqui. Os motivos disso, eu já explanei acima. Até [já promovi uma campanha para tentar melhorar isso há bastante tempo atrás](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2693/132), mas o resultado foi apenas uma leve melhora.

Enfim, na maioria das vezes o problema com as perguntas está em quem pergunta mesmo. Há casos onde o problema é que as pessoas não entendem uma pergunta legítima, mas normalmente esse não é o caso.

Para sanar esse problema, é importante ter zelo com a **REDAÇÃO**. Todos aqueles conceitos chatos que a professora de língua portuguesa insistia nas aulas de redação são muito importantes nessa comunidade, embora poucos se deem conta disso. Lembre-se sempre de descrever bem o problema, de forma detalhada e aprofundada, sem no entanto se delongar demais. Se esforçar na estrutura do texto, na coesão e na coerência do mesmo e na organização textual são coisas muito importantes. Prezar por uma boa formatação e por respeito às normas ortográficas também é muito importante. É importante revisar o texto, revisar de novo, ler o que escreveu, ler novamente, ler uma terceira vez, se colocar no lugar de quem for responder, tentar achar erros e furos na redação, pontos que não ficaram claros, eliminar redundâncias e preencher lacunas, tudo isso é muito importante e muitas vezes negligenciado. E mesmo depois de postado, se ver algum erro ou algo que precisa ser melhorado, não se acanhe em editar. Tente levar os comentários recebidos numa boa, pois na maioria das vezes, eles foram postados por pessoas interessadas em ajudar, mesmo que tenham um tom áspero. Esse processo também é importante nas respostas, mas normalmente são as perguntas que têm maior carência de uma boa redação e são mais propensas a ser mal-redigidas ou mal-interpretadas.

Para as pessoas que vão revisar a pergunta a fim de talvez respondê-la, é importante tentar entender o texto, por pior que ele seja. Comentários que solicitem esclarecimentos devem ter um tom neutro. Em caso de problemas que você saiba como arrumar, não hesite em usar a ferramenta de edição. Se não entende do assunto, mas acha que pode postar um comentário construtivo, vá em frente. E se for o caso de fechar ou mesmo negativar, procure deixar algum comentário se os já existentes não parecerem suficientes. Algumas pessoas podem se irritar com os comentários, mas neste caso você não precisa responder, ao menos não imediatamente, e dependendo do caso, pode sinalizar.

Comment: Entendo o caso. Mas em casos como aconteceu como o meu, foi caso em que o AP (eu) não foi específico e claro o suficiente. Não é o caso deste tópico. Esse tópico trata de DownVoters, votos de fechamento, e duplicatas ilegítima.

Comment: Adcionei também um comentário no post sobre duplicatas ilegítimas

Answer (score 5):

Não há grande forma de resolver, a não ser aconselhar as pessoas.

*Só como exemplo, em que ponto é que eu «domino por completo» uma linguagem ou não? Quem vai avaliar isso? Que direito tenho eu de ir perguntar ao Autor da Pergunta(AP) alguma coisa que eu tenha dúvidas?*

Você está pegando nos termos mais subjetivos do site e está a tentar objetivá-los, está a ir contra o próprio principio que você enuncia de inicio. Eu posso achar que domino uma linguagem e não dominar, como ao contrário. Eu apercebi-me que, quem mais sabe é quem tem a noção do pouco que sabe, num mundo de tanta informação existente. Mas, voltando ao assunto, se eu acho que posso ajudar porque não ir esclarecer com o AP as dúvidas sobre a pergunta?

> «Dê pelo menos duas soluções ou cite dois assuntos do suposto tema
>   "amplo". Sim! Por definição, se o assunto é amplo de verdade, existem
>   no mínimo, duas abordagens ou duas soluções possíveis.»

Qual é a ideia das duas abordagens que eu não percebi?

Por fim, na generalidade, eu entendo o seu ponto e o melhor que se pode fazer é isto, abrir tópico aqui e esperar que as pessoas leiam e tomem consciência do que fazem. Cada pessoa há de ter a sua consciência e a sua convicção do que sabe ou do que não sabe, e não há forma de avaliar isso a não ser esperar que as pessoas tenham bom senso.

Ninguém deveria votar/fechar uma pergunta dum assunto que não entende por completo, mas a realidade é que podem fazê-lo, isto como exemplo. Não querendo me repetir muito, o que se pode tentar fazer é mesmo isto, puxar o assunto e tentar que as pessoas tenham mais cuidado com as perguntas/respostas que analisam nas filas de analise e que votam também.

Mas, como eu ouvi dizer ontem,

> «Convicções são o que são, são as nossas certezas subjetivas.»

Comment: "Qual é a ideia das duas abordagens que eu não percebi?"

Mostrar ao interlocutor que o assunto não é tão simples, e encaminhar ele para ser mais específico. Seria uma boa prática. Ao mesmo tempo desencoraja quem tem uma má prática, de apenas taxar um assunto como amplo.