# Explicações sobre perguntas fechadas por duplicata

Tags: debate

Recentemente tive [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217565/api-gratuita-para-hist%C3%B3rico-climatol%C3%B3gico) fechada por duplicata.

Antes dela ser fechada (quando tinha apenas 2 votos para fechá-la) fiz uma edição na pergunta explicando o porque dela não ter sido respondida na pergunta apontada como possível duplicata (Edição essa desnecessária, pois a pergunta original já era clara o suficiente, mas mesmo assim a fiz).

Mesmo assim, mais 3 pessoas votaram para minha pergunta ser fechada dizendo que ela era uma duplicata.

Essas atitudes já são/foram amplamente discutidas aqui no Stack Meta mas parece que continuam a acontecer, eu sou uma pessoa que começou a participar ativamente do stack há pouquíssimo tempo mas já me desanimei muito devido a essas atitudes.

Este [tópico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2693/campanha-fechamento-justo-e-explicado-reabertura-justa-e-explicada) disserta um pouco sobre o meu problema (que sei que acontece com muitos outros) e em uma das respostas um usuário até diz que *"Eu acho que assim como os novatos podem errar ao criar uma pergunta, os veteranos também podem errar e fechar por engano."* e eu concordo PLENAMENTE com isso, porém no caso de fechar uma pergunta é necessário 5 pessoas para fechá-la, será que 5 veteranos erraram ou desses 5 1 ou 2 erraram e os outros 3 apenas clicaram pra fechar sem ao menos ler a pergunta? Além disso, dos 5 que votaram apenas um deles tentou explicar/me ensinar o porque do fechamento.

Minha sugestão:

- Ao receber 5 votos para fechar a pergunta, a mesma deve ser analisada por uma sexta pessoa que então, explica para o autor pontualmente o porque da pergunta estar sendo fechada caso concorde com os outros 5;

Sei que isso gera um trabalho maior aos moderadores e que pode parecer desnecessário, porém enquanto tivermos pessoas dando downvote/sinalizações sem serem criteriosos acredito que minha sugestão seja válida.

Comment: Neste caso, para que não fiquem dúvidas, os negativos que está a receber aqui é a favor ou contra a sua sugestão.

Comment: Você pode entrar no [Debate da Pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57786/debate-da-pilha) para discutir estas situações.

Comment: @gabrielbelini primeiramente quero que você entenda que o problema não é com você, e sim com o formato da sua pergunta. Para a comunidade não interessa uma lista de links de sites que forneçam uma API de clima (com o histórico ou não), e sim um **problema** relacionado ao uso de uma API ou linguagem, e que possa ser reproduzido por outros usuários. Por tanto, qualquer tentativa de responder sua pergunta não será útil para outras pessoas, e isso acaba prejudicando o site. O máximo que eu posso fazer por você em relação ao seu problema é recomendar o site do [CPTEC](http://www.cptec.inpe.br).

Comment: Oi Gabriel. Tenho dúvidas se esta discussão aqui no meta é mesmo duplicata rs. Porque com esse fechamento ficamos sem lugar para discutir o caso específico da sua pergunta. Eu concordo com vários dos argumentos do Renan abaixo – embora ele às vezes diga as coisas num estilo muito diferente do meu. Ao marcarmos uma pergunta como duplicata aqui, não comparamos apenas as perguntas, mas também suas respostas. Se aquela pergunta está gerando uma lista de APIs de informações climáticas, acho que seria o melhor lugar para abrigar a resposta da sua pergunta [continua...]

Comment: Aquela pergunta poderia até ser editada para mencionar explicitamente a questão das séries históricas, sem grandes prejuízos à resposta atual. Um fator adicional para justificar o fechamento da sua é que listas de recomendação de ferramentas são controversas aqui no site. Elas podem ajudar muita gente, mas ao mesmo tempo as respostas tendem a se tornar desatualizadas. Nunca chegamos a um consenso sobre como lidar com essas perguntas aqui, e muitas acabam fechadas como fora de escopo.

Comment: @gato compreendi, vou dar uma olhada no site e ver se encontro alguma coisa, obrigado!

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu marquei como duplicata pois entendi que ela poderia ser discutida no tópico apontado, porém concordo que fica complicado se expressar de forma completa usando apenas os comentários do SO. O que vc diz no final do seu comentário é uma coisa que levei muito em consideração antes de criar a pergunta, eu sempre penso umas 300 vezes antes de postar qualquer coisa no SO pois sei que o escopo é restrito e perguntas mal feitas são ignoradas/downvotadas/etc. Outra coisa que concordo é que minha pergunta poderia ter sido "anexada" à pergunta que disseram que é uma duplicata [continua]

Comment: Mesmo ela não tendo sido respondida no tópico apontado, ela trata de um assunto muito parecido, porém eu sinceramente não sei como faria algo do tipo. Teria eu que solicitar uma edição para a pergunta original e adicionar a minha dúvida? Ou então adicionar uma resposta solicitando que alguém contribua com o que eu solicitei...

Comment: Você sugerir edição é sim um caminho. Mas não é errado o que você fez, de postar suas próprias perguntas. Por mais que não pareça pra muita gente, marcação de duplicata não é sinal de problema sério na pergunta, é só uma indicação de que a resposta fica em outro lugar. É vantajoso ter múltiplas perguntas apontando pra uma única. Dá mais chance de as pessoas encontrarem o que querem via mecanismos de busca, já que cada um expõe seu problema de um jeito.

Comment: Entendi, de fato eh vantajoso ter perguntas flagueadas como duplicata que levam a outro topico onde a mesma eh respondida, mas pra isso a pergunta tem que ser respondida em um lugar ou outro. Como a minha não foi, o correto, caso ela nao se encaixe nas diretrizes do site, seria fecha-la por outro motivo (baseada em opiniao, sugestao de ferramenta, etc) e nao duplicata. Mas pelo visto eu devo ser o único que pensa dessa forma baseado nos upvotes da resposta (diga-se de passagem desnecessariamente agressiva) do @Renan.

Answer (score 6):

Sua pergunta sobre API's com histórico é uma duplicata.

Já existia [uma pergunta sobre API's de meteorologia, com diversas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117118/como-pegar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-clima-e-tempo). Você queria uma API de meteorologia que tenha uma feature a mais.

Você poderia verificar as que estão sugeridas na pergunta da qual a sua é duplicata. Caso nenhuma lhe fosse conveniente, uma rápida pesquisa lhe daria algumas alternativas:

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=weather+api+with+history

E você poderia complementar a pergunta original com mais uma resposta.

Você preferiu abrir uma pergunta para obter um detalhe a mais. Assim, ao invés de termos uma pergunta com uma lista de API's para resolver um problema - o que por si só já é quase um problema, pois essas perguntas tendem a atrair respostas apenas com links - teríamos duas  perguntas com listas de API's para resolver o mesmo problema, com uma diferença mínima de escopo.

Dito isso, vamos à sugestão dada sobre o que fazer com duplicatas:

> Minha sugestão:
>
> - Ao receber 5 votos para fechar a pergunta, a mesma deve ser analisada por uma sexta pessoa que então, explica para o autor pontualmente o porque da pergunta estar sendo fechada caso concorde com os outros 5;

Não é necessário escrever para o autor o que está errado com a pergunta. O texto que aparece em perguntas marcadas como pendentes não é copiado e colado de um template, é colocado automaticamente pelo sistema e explica exatamente o que as pessoas estavam pensando quando votaram para fechar.

> Sei que isso gera um trabalho maior aos moderadores(...)

A esmagadora maioria das perguntas não é marcada como pendente pelos moderadores. Quem se dá ao trabalho de fazer isso são [usuários comuns que já possuem reputação suficiente para tomar a decisão de votar para fechar a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

> (...) e que pode parecer desnecessário (...)

Acredito que realmente é.

> (...) porém enquanto tivermos pessoas dando downvote/sinalizações sem serem criteriosos acredito que minha sugestão seja válida.

São necessários cinco votos para suspender uma pergunta, e cinco para reabrir, porque essas coisas têm que ser feitas através de consenso da comunidade.

A sua pergunta está na fila de reabertura. Caso seja o consenso da comunidade de que é uma boa pergunta, ela será reaberta.

O Stack Overflow tem bastante sucesso por vários fatores, sendo um dos principais a forma como o conteúdo é tratado. O esforço da própria comunidade em separar o joio do trigo é o que faz com que ele seja mais útil para a comunidade de desenvolvimento de software do que sites como o *Quora* e fóruns de `insira qualquer linguagem aqui`. Se você acha que o site chegou até aqui através da colaboração de pessoas que não têm critério no que fazem, talvez o *Yahoo! Respostas* ou o *Experts Exchange* lhe sejam mais agradáveis.

Comment: "Sua pergunta sobre API's com histórico é uma duplicata." Não, não é. Não responde minha pergunta nem me ajuda a chegar no resultado que eu quero, então, não é uma duplicata. "Você poderia verificar as que estão sugeridas na pergunta da qual a sua é duplicata. Caso nenhuma lhe fosse conveniente, uma rápida pesquisa lhe daria algumas alternativas:
http://lmgtfy.com/?q=weather+api+with+history". Pesquisei e muito antes de perguntar, como sempre faço pra não adicionar "lixo" no forum, nada me ajudou por isso criei a pergunta no stack.

Comment: O fato de que a única resposta na sua pergunta é literalmente o primeiro resultado no Google é evidência contra a existência dessa pesquisa.

Comment: @gabrielbelini além da sua pergunta ser duplicata, ela também é fora de escopo, já que ela pede por recomendação de serviços de terceiro, e gratuito ainda.

Comment: O fato de que eu imediatamente comentei nessa resposta dizendo a quem a postou que essa API não fornece histórico climatologico gratuito é evidência de que eu pesquisei e muito antes de postar, inclusive, essa API foi a primeira na qual procurei pelo histórico.

Comment: @gato concordo que pode ser entendida como fora de escopo, alias, li bastante a Ajuda e alguns topicos do Meta antes de postar para ter onde me basear caso alguém argumentasse isso. Minha pergunta é sobre "ferramentas comuns entre programadores" e não faz comparações entre APIs ou coisas do tipo, apenas solicita UMA ferramenta ou forma que resolva meu problema (o qual eu cheguei a conclusão que não pode ser resolvido gratuitamente).