# 100.000 perguntas ativas!

Tags: debate, comunidade

Pouco mais de 4 anos depois e chegamos nas cem mil perguntas feitas e mantidas. Foram muito mais se considerarmos as que não sobreviveram, então são perto das 300 mil postagens no total.

## Minha experiência no SOpt

Tenho orgulho de ter [proposto a criação do site em 2010](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese) quando comecei ficar mais íntimo da rede (até [fui moderador no Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/389/maniero)) que logo gostei em 2008. Foram 3 anos de espera até o lançamento do site.

[image: Página da proposta aprovada do SOpt]

Mesmo sendo muito mal recebido no Stack Overflow original em inglês, e até foi merecido porque fiz tudo errado, vi que ali tinha algo diferente. Não só uma ferramenta mais interessante, mas uma cultura forte, e principalmente gente fantástica com um conhecimento que eu nem imaginava ser possível em humanos :) Graças a ação do [Joel Spolsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky) e [Jeff Atwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood).

Tenho dois marcos em minha vida profissional:

- um quando [trabalhei na Dape Software](https://www.linkedin.com/in/maniero/) e conheci um dos profissionais mais completos que pode existir e que me mostrou o quanto eu era um <strike>bosta</strike> profissional abaixo da mediocridade. Me deu a base que me faltava, me mostrou coisas que que eu não vi nem na faculdade, que me tornou o pragmático que sou, depois de muitos puxões de orelha, quase todos merecidos :). Aos poucos, até com atraso, fui começando entender como as coisas são de fato na computação e aprendi não me apaixonar por tecnologias (tá bom, [me apaixonei pelo Clipper :) mas já foi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43902/101)), metodologias, etc., apenas a adotá-las em benefício do projeto. Aprendi que programador adora acreditar em saci pererê, papai noel e coisas do tipo (palavras dele). Ele me viciou em escrever código performático e até hoje não me livrei do vício :) As histórias que tenho pra contar dos ganhos de performance que ele conseguia, e que deixava as pessoas de boca aberta, não cabem aqui.
- o segundo foi o SO. Tive acesso aos melhores profissionais do mercado me ensinando como se faz código com qualidade no mundo real e de forma moderna. Não dá para citar todos mas imediatamente fiquei fã do [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (quem não?) e principalmente do [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert), o que copiei o estilo sempre que pude, ainda que eu não tenha nem perto da capacidade técnica e articulação dele, o que somado ao jeito meio paranoico de brasileiros fez eu colecionar alguns *haters*, nunca foi minha intenção, mas aceito o fardo :)

O bom é que colecionei muitos amigos, mesmo que virtualmente realmente considero alguns como amigos. Posso não ser a pessoa mais fácil do mundo, mas quem quer ser meu amigo, ou pelo menos colega, consegue, basta entender que eu quero ajudar e que entendo que passar a mão na cabeça não ajuda. Sem querer entrar em questões filosóficas e sociológicas, temos visto isto cada vez mais em nossa sociedade. O verdadeiro amigo é aquele que te critica quando precisa e não o que te elogia porque é o que faz ele ser mais palatável para você.

Mais ainda, [me tornei Microsoft MVP](https://mvp.microsoft.com/pt-br/PublicProfile/5002397?fullName=Antonio%20%20Maniero) por causa do site e da colaboração de vocês, e agora estou expandindo minha influência para além do site, dando palestras, participando mais ativamente de redes, especialmente do Linkedin (segue lá :) ), e em breve trarei novidades que muitos vão gostar.

Não saí muito da mediocridade e não vejo isso necessariamente como algo negativo, embora meu desejo é que fosse diferente. Não por falta de esforço, mas por limitações pessoais, a gente é o que é. Mas melhorei muito nestes 4 anos, até para questionar melhor os erros dos outros :D

O mérito todo do sucesso do site é de vocês. Já sabem mas não custa reafirmar.

Está legal, mas eu queria que fosse melhor. Sei que chego ser chato quando reclamo, mas é só porque quero o melhor para todos, ainda que eu possa estar errado.

De qualquer forma vocês me deram mais alegrias que tristezas (e foram poucos que o fizeram assim). Avancei muito profissional e pessoalmente por causa de vocês, ao que meu muito obrigado é pouco.

[image: Screenshot da página principal com os 100 mil cravados]

## O que podemos melhorar?

Mas para não ficar no discurso, talvez piegas, o que podemos fazer para melhorar?

Perdemos total ou parcialmente alguns usuários importantes. Alguns porque não conseguem conviver com a visão de outras pessoas, esses não tem muito o que fazer, é algo pessoal, outros não sabemos bem porque, e isto tem feito a qualidade das respostas decair, inclusive as minhas. Concorrência é bom :)

Sinto falta de ser questionado por bons profissionais, isto sempre fez eu aprender. Este é um dos pontos fortes do nosso site.

Muitos usuários parecem cansados de ter que gerenciar tantos problemas, até mesmo de ver tudo o que postam.

Não crescemos mais entre a quantidade de perguntas diárias. [Deveríamos ser terceiro ou quarto site mais ativo da rede](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

Sinto também um pouco, só um pouco, a falta de sentimento de comunidade mesmo. E não tenho ideia de como resolver isto.

Dê seu depoimento sobre o sua participação, mas dê também sua visão do que podemos fazer para melhorar a participação no site. Aproveite e diga o que eu faço de errado como moderador e usuário, quero melhorar ;)

**Precisamos pensar em algo diferente no nível macro**.

Comment: Vida longa ao SOpt!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XypLi.png

Comment: Viva o SOpt! Muito orgulho de ter feito parte da Área 51 e entrado como usuário número 100 do site. Sinto falta da época do Beta e dos "gigantes"da época. Eu mesmo não tenho mais muito tempo para o site, saí do Facebook onde tinha algum contato com o pessoal e nunca fui muito adepto do chat. Minhas tentativas de promover encontros também falharem miseravelmente. Dito isso o SOpt se tornou, com certeza, o melhor site sobre programação em português da atualidade! Fico muito feliz de ter conhecido toda essa galera.

Comment: É sensacional e contagiante, ver que temos pessoas que acreditam nas outras, que ajudam sem esperar o mínimo por isso. Conheço muito pouco de programação, e menos ainda de inglês, então o SOpt é essencial para mim. Parabéns pela iniciativa, e pela conquista.

Comment: Acho que o principal problema que temos como usuários experientes é o *no soup for you*. Pretendo criar uma pergunta aqui no meta para falar sobre ele.

Comment: @VictorStafusa acho ótimo.

Comment: O Eric Lippert é incrível, de longe a figura que mais admiro no SOen; especialmente porque ele costuma escrever sobre compiladores e design de linguagens (são assuntos que me interessam bastante). Ah, o [blog dele](https://ericlippert.com/) é muito bom também, recomendo a todos.

Comment: @Gabriel sim, acompanho. Também gosto muito da área.

Answer (score 16):

Olá, Maniero!

Eu gosto muito da filosofia do SO e admiro muito sua participação aqui no SOpt :)

Tenho a impressão que o SOpt, no passado, era muito mais ativo. Percebo isto pois [em 2015](https://stackexchange.com/users/2774008/dherik?tab=reputation), com pouca dedicação, eu conseguia responder mais perguntas pois existiam mais perguntas pendentes.

Hoje a impressão que tenho do SOpt é de pouca movimentação. Assim, acabo sendo mais ativo no SOen.

Das razões que posso citar:

- Há sempre perguntas frescas no SO aguardando resposta, então acabo me dedicando mais lá do que aqui.
- Já percebi algumas coisas que não gostei lendo o [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=pt.stackoverflow.com) do SOpt. Exemplos:

  - Alguns usuários desmerecendo um pouco respostas ou perguntas dos usuários.
  - Usuário preparando perguntas com outros membros, do tipo "eu levanto e você corta" lá no chat. Embora qualquer um possa responder uma pergunta já respondida, os usuários sempre vão preferir focar seus esforços em uma pergunta sem resposta.
- Sempre que tenho alguma dúvida, acabo correndo para o SOen para ter uma resposta mais rápida e, talvez, mais completa, por existir mais usuários ativos lá.
- Tempos atrás (2015) havia certos usuários no site que, embora tecnicamente excelentes, promoviam um pouco de confusão desnecessária. Nunca parei para analisar nisto, mas isto deve ter influenciado minha inatividade aqui.

Entendo que exista, ainda assim, muito espaço para o SOpt, principalmente para aqueles que ainda não estão confortáveis com o idioma gringo.

Aos mais experientes, eu poderia sugerir (e serve para mim também):

- Priorizar as dúvidas aqui no SOpt antes de correr para o SOen
- Sempre que possível, participar do chat. Creio que isto remova um pouco a impressão de que poucos usuários estão ativos no site e incentivem, mais ainda, os usuários ativos.
- Talvez, promover eventos entre os usuários do SOpt e divulgá-los.
- Entre colegas de trabalho, mostrar a [importância do SO](https://qualidadegarantida.blogspot.com.br/2018/02/por-que-todo-desenvolvedor-deveria-ter.html) para eles mesmos.
- Ter **muito** cuidado com a recepção de novos membros, vide resposta do @Vanderlei e recente [artigo do próprio SO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1). Estando mais ativo aqui, pude perceber a quantidade grande de usuários novos aqui por dia, precisamos cuidar deste pessoal para que eles gostem, fiquem e participem :).Assim, temos que pensar duas vezes antes de negativar uma pergunta ou resposta de alguém que **acabou de chegar** ao site. Dá para notar que tem um pessoal com o dedo pesado para votar negativo, acredito que a moderação até poderia monitorar mais de perto. Aqui, neste post mesmo, várias respostas foram negativadas sem um comentário sequer.

Vou pensar mais um pouco aqui para ver se surge mais algo.

Comment: Legal. Vejo da mesma forma. Era este tipo de post que eu queria ver.

Comment: @Articuno, você entendeu corretamente. Mas é minha visão pessoal, não estou pedindo para concordar. Também não afirmei que é errado ou que é intencional, e claro que há casos que não há problema algum (como o que citou). . Mas, ao meu ver, você acaba excluindo alguns usuários que poderiam responder a pergunta, pois dá uma vantagem para outros que estão no chat. Como a nossa comunidade é pequena, creio que isto afete o seu crescimento. Já respondi perguntas assim simplesmente porque eu estava "monitorando" o chat e em cenários diferentes do que citou.

Comment: "_Dá para notar que tem um pessoal com o dedo pesado para votar negativo_".... isso é fato! E pior, não deixam comments, tornando a vida do AR ou AP um pesadelo e desestimulando... e pior ainda, são usuários experientes que fazem isso... e pior mais ainda, se vc vai reclamar eles perdem a paciência...

Comment: Gostei muito desse comentário sobre os novatos. Assim que entrei respondi uma pergunta apenas com um link esclarecendo a pessoa. Não sabia e não tinha visto ainda outras postagens. Simplesmente recebi negativo sem saber pq. Fiquei anos fora do site por isso. Vale mais explicar do q negativar um usuário novato, já que ele está começando e precisa aprender.

Answer (score 14):

Sou um usuário antigo do SOpt, eu estava lá na Area 51 (embora tenha entrado só na fase de commit). Recebi o e-mail do Gabe e me juntei ao site logo nas primeiras horas do beta privado. Tenho a camiseta do SOpt. Hoje sou o #12 em pontos de reputação aqui do site.

A minha participação por aqui tem e teve altos e baixos. Houve períodos que me afastei do site e participava pouco. Houve períodos em que respondia a diversas perguntas de forma bastante impulsiva.

Poucas foram as vezes onde entrei em embate com algum usuário por aqui. Isso é muito positivo, vez que antes do SOpt (ou mesmo do SOen) ser criado, quando eu participava do GUJ, tinha o costume de ser bem encrenqueiro e troll e me metia em polêmicas frequentemente, colecionando também alguns inimigos. Já por aqui, como não temos perguntas opinativas ou que degringolam em conversa de boteco, isso não ocorre, o que é bastante positivo.

Entretanto, o ambiente do SO (seja o SOpt ou do SOen) não é nada amigável para quem não sabe como as coisas funcionam. Antes do SOpt existir, eu já era usuário do SOen, e sabia que as coisas lá eram um tanto difíceis. Sempre que pensava em publicar algo (seja pergunta ou resposta), já ficava apreensivo e pensando como me proteger de ataques de outros usuários sem que isso pudesse se voltar contra mim. Esse é o problema principal do SOpt/SOen.

Isso tudo mostra bem qual é o maior problema que o StackOverflow tem, seja em PT ou em EN. A vida para quem está começando no site é difícil e árdua. Acertar uma forma aceitável de fazer perguntas é complicado e doloroso, e a maior parte dos usuários novos não consegue passar por esse processo. Isso ocorre obviamente porque novos usuários frequentemente fazem perguntas opinativas, fora do contexto ou muito mal elaboradas. As respostas de usuários novos também tendem a ser bem ruins. Foi pensando nesses problemas que elaborei a [Campanha: Fechamento justo e explicado. Reabertura justa e explicada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2693/132) e também o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/132). Também considero [Eu não sei perguntar, e você?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4829/132), [Gorila vs Tubarão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/132) e [O que é o "problema XY"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132) como perguntas muito importantes aqui no meta nesse sentido. Estou pensando também em elaborar mais algumas desse tipo.

O principal problema é sempre esse. O SOpt, assim como o SOen (e grande parte dos sites da StackExchange) são hostis para usuários novos. A solução por parte dos usuários mais experientes é aquilo que todos já sabem mas mesmo assim vejo poucos fazendo:

- Antes de votar para fechar uma pergunta, deixar um comentário.
- Antes de negativar, deixar um comentário.
- Um comentário pode valer muito mais que um voto negativo.
- Não tenha pressa para negativar.
- Não deixe de votar positivo também. Vejo que hoje aqui está mais difícil de se ganhar votos positivos do que já foi um dia.
- Não é só porque você está vendo uma pergunta ou resposta ruim na fila de análise que isso significa que você não precise comentar.

Entretanto, ainda tem o lado de que a comunidade me parece um pouco mais chata nesses últimos tempos. Dentre as opções que podemos usar para chacoalhar e reanimar um pouco mais as coisas por aqui:

- Organizar mais encontros presenciais.
- Mais perguntas para semear conteúdo na comunidade. O Maniero já fez bastante disso.
- Desafios ou torneios de programação.
- Camisetas ou algum outro tipo de souvenir a distribuir como recompensa por colaborações.

Answer (score 11):

**O SOpt está de parabéns!**

Boas Maniero, tu és um dos grandes responsáveis do sucesso deste site, muito do conteúdo de qualidade foi gerado por ti. Claro que sem desconsiderar ninguém, temos muitos bons contribuidores.
Parabéns a todos nós!

Quanto aos problemas eu acho que um dos principais problemas do SOpt é a falta de reconhecimento que as pessoas sentem pelo trabalho que prestam, ora não sendo reconhecidas com votos nas perguntas, ora sendo negativadas sem nenhuma explicação, o chamado *like à lá facebook*.

No meu caso, eu sempre contribui mais a moderar o site que efetivamente a responder a perguntas e o que me desmotivou a mim foi precisamente a falta de reconhecimento do meu trabalho. Não me estou a queixar de nada, mas foi o que realmente senti.

Um exemplo disso é o Maniero, que o reconhecimento dele chegou, mas demorou para chegar, acredito que ele muitas vezes deve ter pensado no tempo que despendia aqui, e talvez em abrandar a participação (?!). Admiro muito a sua persistência e como ele carregou muito tempo o SOpt para cima.

Mas claro, o SOpt não é só coisas más, eu conheci aqui muita gente com que troco ideias quase todos os dias, e que me ajudaram a evoluir muito. Algumas respostas de utilizadores mais experientes ajudaram-me muito a compreender temas que eu tinha alguma dificuldade em compreender, como a segurança.

Acho que no todo a minha experiência de SOpt é bem positiva, embora a vontade de participar hoje em dia seja pouca.

Espero longa vida ao site e que vocês possam ter o retorno, quanto mais não seja de aprendizagem, que pode ser um bom incentivo para participarem no site!

Comment: Sabe que eu acho até o contrário :) Esse reconhecimento com votos tem ocorrido menos agora, e de fato, queira ou não, desmotiva um pouco, os votos dão uma satisfação pessoal, é o nosso "pagamento". Mas eu entendo isso, ocorre o mesmo comigo. Chega um ponto que começa cansar você ter que analisar tudo, que precisa resolver problemas na maioria das postagens para ficar com a qualidade que desejamos. Esse modelo de ter todas tecnologias é ótimo pra evitar a bolha, mas também cria muita carga para todos. E acho que temos o problema da cidade pequena. O que ocorreu aqui é igual ao SOen, ...

Comment: ... as pessoas cansam. Lá tem a vantagem que acaba sempre entrando gente nova disposta a assumir um pouco da moderação, aqui isso quase não ocorre (claro, tem um pessoal novo legal que está ajudando, nem vou tentar citar alguns pra ñ ficar gente fora, mas não é suficiente), e acho que a falta de outras pessoas de qualidade pra me ensinar coisas (ainda tem alguns) e me questionar construtivamente (ainda tem um ou outro) também desestimula um pouco. Por outro lado temos menos trolls, e por isso me meto em menos confusão :D

Comment: Obrigado por falar na persistência, porque tem hora que dá vontade de desistir, mas eu exercito o mantra que nem tudo será como eu desejo, e aí me concentro nas inúmeras coisas boas que o SOpt me traz. Mas se fosse o SOpt fosse começar hoje eu faria várias coisas diferentes.

Comment: Eu realmente não tenho grande conhecimento deste último ano, acredito que esteja diferente, é bom para a comunidade.

Answer (score 8):

Primeiramente parabéns pela ideia da criação do site e pelo sucesso que se tornou, eu fui durante muito tempo apenas "leitor" do Stack Overflow/SOpt e só agora estou usando tanto para perguntar como para ajudar nas respostas.

Uma sugestão que gostaria de registrar é que a moderação aqui no SOpt possa ser mais "leve", porque a quantidade e a qualidade das respostas as vezes não é muito boa e principalmente porque muito rigor em alguns casos afasta novos usuários e até impede soluções.

Por exemplo, o amigo aqui ([Erro ao converter inteiro nulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292374/erro-ao-converter-inteiro-nulo)) provavelmente está procurando uma resposta até agora, e ele só precisaria de uma resposta do tipo:

> "Você não pode converter nulo em int desta forma, use `Convert.ToInt32(detalhe.GANO_ID_ATIV)` no lugar"

Porém ele só tem links para respostas muito mais abrangentes. Não seria o caso de registrar uma resposta e manter apenas o "possível duplicada"?

Aconteceu comigo também de dar uma resposta que foi convertida em comentário por não ser "detalhada o suficiente" ([SQL Melhoria de procedimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291502/sql-melhoria-de-procedimento/291961#291961)). Aqui acho que foram dois problemas:

- Não "detalhada o suficiente" é muito relativo, e para uma pergunta que não tinha respostas acho que foi um pouco rigoroso.
- Mesmo aceitando e editando a resposta para detalha-la conforme o recomendado, a resposta só volta a ficar ativa depois de alguns votos (o que não aconteceu até agora);

Eu acabei postando outra resposta mais tarde, desta vez mais completa, mas o problema é que a pessoa que perguntou provavelmente precisava de uma resposta mais rápida e não conseguiu. Neste caso uma sugestão de edição em um comentário teria sido muito mais efetiva.

Answer (score 7):

## TL;DR Que todos os outros usuários não sejam como eu!

#### Não posso, não quero, não faço

Esta resposta aplica-se apenas para mim. Eu encontro bastantes dificuldades em manter-me como usuário ativo qualquer que seja a comunidade e tópico.

Parece que há uma inércia infinita que me previne de despender demasiado do meu <s>tempo</s> (creio que não seja uma questão de tempo, talvez seja mais de atenção?) dentro duma comunidade seja qual for o fim dessa comunidade.

Eu gosto de participar com perguntas e respostas mas apenas **quando quero**, **para o que quero**, **sobre o que quero**. Talvez seja um pouco de egocentrismo, talvez não.

A minha participação na comunidade muito provavelmente com 99.999% de certeza manter-se-á como está, ou seja continuarei a ser um usuário não muito ativo.

Por outra perspectiva posso concluir também que o aspecto de gamificação não é o suficiente para me manter ativo na comunidade. Não sei se há algo que possa ser feito para melhorar: **este é um problema meu, não da comunidade**.

Dizem que reconhecer um problema é o primeiro passo para o resolver, mas não se esqueçam, minha inércia é infinita.

#### Concluo esperando que continue havendo SOpt para muitos anos que hão de vir e que continue havendo boas contribuições por parte de todos.

Comment: Eu acho que todos de alguma forma são assim, até mesmo quando são pagos, embora neste caso talvez se aceite ser mais flexível. Em comunidade tem que fazer o que gosta mesmo. Por causa da gamificação fiz algumas que não era bem o que gostava :)

Answer (score 7):

6 meses de atividade praticamente diária no SOpt, e aprendi muitas coisas aqui, não apenas e principalmente em melhorar o meu código, mas em lidar com pessoas, com uma comunidade virtual.

Eu era um usuário eventual do SOen. Recorria a ele quando não achava saída para os meus problemas de código e sempre consegui solução lá. E fiquei bem contente quando vi que havia o site em Pt. E como eu gosto de participar de sites de perguntas e respostas, o SOpt caiu como uma luva.

Só me arrependo de não ter descoberto bem antes, visto que o site tem mais de 4 anos. Mas espero que dure muito tempo e que eu possa seguir firme nele. Muitas coisas já tentaram me desanimar, mas como eu tenho tempo disponível e vontade de ajudar, sigo firme como nunca, ciente da contribuição satisfatória que estou dando.

No mais, desejo sucesso a todos e vida longa ao SOpt!

Answer (score 7):

Parabéns e obrigado pelo trabalho, e assim como você tem de exemplo outros profissionais, certamente você também é para muitos (vou tentando conseguir esses códigos performáticos como você faz).

Em um primeiro contato pode parecer estranho sua "sinceridade", (brasileiro não é acostumado com isso) mas só quem não sabe receber uma crítica e seguir em frente é que vira hater, e como falou, é o preço que se paga.

Participo da comunidade a 1 ano, e entrei porque durante muito tempo busquei ajuda aqui (de forma anonima) e sempre tive resultados, então resolvi aparecer para ajudar também. Fui bem ativo até atingir minha meta de 10k pontos depois disso já diminui a atividade (falta tempo também).

Alguns pontos que, acredito eu, poderiam melhorar a comunidade:

- Habilitar a aba `JOBS` como tem no `SO`: Poderia melhorar a recompensa que o usuário tem em se manter ativo na comunidade ($$), ao invés de ter apenas a gamificação.
- Tentar incentivar o registro do usuário na comunidade: Assim como eu no passado, conheço alguns que só acessam o site pra ver as respostas de forma anonima, não dão feedback de forma nenhuma.
- Alertar usuários de baixa reputação que é necessário colocar um exemplo mínimo verificável na pergunta: Muitos sequer acessam o `Tour`, fazem perguntas vagas, recebem muitos votos negativos e a pergunta fechada logo de cara. Isso é ruim para o novo membro em sua primeira experiência na comunidade, e é ruim para quem já é ativo ter que ficar perguntando "e qual o erro?", "coloque o código que já fez", etc...

Sem mais, só tenho a agradecer a comunidade.

Obrigado.

Comment: Sim, uma das coisas que odeio é a pessoas falarem que odeiam mentiras, quando isso é uma grande mentira. tenho consciência que muitos não gostam do meu jeito. Eu faço tudo para colaborar, do jeito que eu acho que é importante, não sou de passar a mão na cabeça, já tem bastante pessoas que fazem isso, falo o que as pessoas precisam ouvir para evoluir. Posso estar erado em muita coisa, mas eu tento o meu melhor. O que falo não para prejudicar ninguém, diminuir, espezinhar, embora quando se pisa no meu calo, não respondo por mim :D Obrigado pelo post.

Answer (score 5):

Muito conhecimento que tenho, devo ao SOpt.
Ajudo no que posso e aprendo o que desejo.
Mas, como toda comunidade, existe o seu grau de **toxicidade**, não tanto por ofensas, mas por pensamentos e atos. Um desses atos é classificado até como um pecado capital: **A PREGUIÇA**.

O conhecimento, em uma analogia, digo que é um ser sem membros para locomoção, onde temos que, em todo lugar, levá-lo conosco, sendo assim, ele nunca vem até a gente.

Esperando esse conhecimento que nunca vem, as pessoas se acomodam e acabam ficando estacionadas e sem um propósito de saber se algo já existe, se pessoas já foram ajudada, ou mesmo se ela já foi ajudada com esse problema e pode ajudar os outros. O mundo está se fechando a reter conhecimento, infelizmente.

Quando esse pensamento deixar de existir ou, na melhor das hipóteses, se dissipar um pouco, nossa comunidade crescerá e colherá muitos frutos.